# What kind of timestamp is this?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, datetime-format, time-format

I write an application that has to mimick the behavior of a certain telephony server.

I see it sending timestamps that are not in the Unix time_t format.

For example 303502349 is some time on December 16th, 2013.

Any idea what kind of timestamp format that is ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date) and then check whether 303502349 seconds or milliseconds fits one of those epochs...