# Why are all these timestamps from 2011?

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp

I wasn't sure what format `13136436720872065` was in, so I divided it by 10 until it worked out--but now all my answers are from 2011, even though I know the timestamps shouldn't be!

```
>>> time.gmtime(13136436720872065/10**7)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=5, tm_min=1, tm_sec=12, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=230, tm_isdst=0)
```

Comment: @Alnitak I actually know the exact reason, answering my own question while you posted that

Comment: Right, and so I saw, but as a question this is posed pretty poorly.   Without the evidence, or perhaps a suggestion of what you thought the correct time should be, it's unlikely anyone else would be able to produce an answer.

Comment: It's a difference in [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of timestamp is this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632340/what-kind-of-timestamp-is-this)

Comment: A more appropriate way to phrase this question would be: "I have a timestamp value 13136436720872065 which is supposed to represent a time sometime in April 2017.  I tried converting it to a Unix timestamp by dividing by 10e7 but that gives me a date in 2011.   Can anyone suggest what sort of timestamp this is?"

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara it's not just epoch - it would help if that wikipedia page also happened to indicate the standard unit of measurement (i.e. seconds for Unix time, milliseconds for JS, microseconds for NTFS) for the offset from the epoch.

Answer (score -1):

The timestamps you're converting are actually Windows timestamps, not unix timestamps.

- **Unix** timestamps are given in seconds since January 1, 1970. Sometimes you will encounter milliseconds (x1000) as a format as well.
- **Windows** timestamps are given in milliseconds since January 1, 1600.

The correct conversion is:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(1601,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=13136436720872065)
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 12, 2, 12, 0, 872065)
```

Comment: and what language is that test performed in?